# Hibernate cascading throws Exception on save

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping, cascade

I'm trying to insert an object in the database. It contains a collection which also should be inserted, but I'm getting the exception below:

```
SQLServerException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID_CUSTOMER', table 'dbo.CUSTOMER_ADDRESS'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

The mapping is as follows:

**CustomerDB.java**

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "customer", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<CustomerAddressDB> addresses;
```

**CustomerAddressDB.java**

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_CUSTOMER", nullable = false, updatable=false, insertable=false)
private CustomerDB customer;
```

So, when I call the persist method for the CustomerDB entity I can see the HQL being executed:

```
Hibernate: insert into M2M_CUSTOMER (NM_COMPANY_NAME, DT_CREATED, ID_PARENT, ID_LAYER, DS_OBS, DS_SHORT_NAME, ID_CUSTOMER_STATUS, NM_TRADING_NAME) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into M2M_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS (DS_CITY, DS_COUNTRY, NR_NUMBER, NR_POSTAL_CODE, DS_STATE, DS_STREET, ID_ADDRESS_TYPE) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

but after this the exception mentioned earlier is thrown. I can't understand why it says the CUSTOMER_ID is null, as the customer is being inserted before the address. Is there a mapping mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: Which annotation do you have in your Customer's 'id' field?

Answer (score 0):

You're telling Hibernate that the customer in the Address entity should not be inserted nor updated, so Hibernate doesn't insert it. Replace

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_CUSTOMER", nullable = false, updatable=false, insertable=false)
private CustomerDB customer;
```

by

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_CUSTOMER", nullable = false)
private CustomerDB customer;
```